# which object calls constructor faster?

Tags: c++, performance, constructor

I have two different classes in which different type of constructor call is shown. Which of these will execute faster ?

```
class A
{ 
    string x, y;
public:
    A(char *i,char *j): x(i), y(j) {}
};

class B
{
    string x, y;
public:
    B(char *i, char *j){ x = i; y = j; }
};

int main()
{
    A a("hello", "world");//line 1
    B b("hello", "world");//line 2
}
```

Which of these lines will execute faster ?

Comment: What is stopping you from timing them yourself?

Comment: There will be no meaningful difference in any realistic scenario. But there' a bunch of better reasons than speed to prefer `:x(i),y(j)`

Comment: Just always us the member initializer list to initialize class members.  const members and reference members can only be initialized there so to be consistent you should do everything else there as well.

Comment: @Jeffrey so we can say that line 1 will execute faster right ?

Comment: @NeilButterworth: *"What is stopping you from timing them yourself?"* Compiler, as it doesn't compile ;-)

Comment: @AsifSiddiqui as Jeffrey said, speed is not the reason. There is a lot of reasons why the first is generally considered good practice. Speed is very low in the list of reasons. This kind of optimisation should be very low in your priorities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop worrying about micro optimisations. They will both run as fast unless your compiler is from 1920. Make your code readable and easy to understand is the most important.

Comment: I challenge you to find a C++ compiler from 1920.

Comment: @SergeyA https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_Kylix this has a Greek theme I guess, it's something.

Comment: I think neither will execute faster, because neither will compile.

Answer (score 0):

If there would be a difference, it would be negligible.

However, it's considered a good practice to use initializers and directly initialize members with the right value.

Another reason is that this approach would let less window for error, as one could use members before initializing them inside the constructor.

There is many reasons why initializer list is considered good practice, and sometimes you don't have the choice but to use them in some situation. Speed is not the matter here.